# How to fetch exact data from multiple dictionaries that I am receiving at client side over python websocket?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, websocket

I am trying to fetch ltp (last traded price or 'lp' in below attached output) for some stocks via brokers api as follow :

```
 api.subscribe(
     [
         "NFO|43232",
         "NFO|43207",
         "NFO|43224",
         "NFO|43206",
         "NFO|43228",
         "NFO|43214",
         "NFO|43221",
         "NFO|43220",
     ]
 )
```

In the above code NFO= "exchange" and corresponding number 43232 is a token number (tk) of the stock, that's how I can subscribe to multiple stocks and below is the callback function where I am receiving the data where I can do data operation like **ltp_data = tick_data["lp"]** in which I am assigning 'lp' of a single stock to a global variable ltp_data which keeps getting updated as new data arrives, but I am having issue when doing the same for multiple stocks.

```
 def event_handler_feed_update(tick_data):
     print(type(tick_data))
     global ltp_data
     print(f"feed update {tick_data}")
```

and here is the sample output -

```
feed update {'t': 'tk', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43207', 'ts': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20600', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 'ti': '0.05', 'lp': '0.05', 'pc': '-98.44', 'c': '3.20', 'ft': '1701942487', 'o': '1.80', 'h': '2.00', 'l': '0.05', 'ap': '0.88', 'v': '206011850', 'oi': '12497750', 'poi': '7224700', 'bp1': '0.05', 'sp1': '0.10', 'bq1': '770100', 'sq1': '852450'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tk', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43224', 'ts': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20800', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 'ti': '0.05', 'lp': '102.65', 'pc': '-38.40', 'c': '166.65', 'ft': '1701942487', 'o': '164.55', 'h': '164.55', 'l': '59.10', 'ap': '97.94', 'v': '173139250', 'oi': '3691200', 'poi': '2623400', 'bp1': '102.65', 'sp1': '102.75', 'bq1': '1450', 'sq1': '450'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tk', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43206', 'ts': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20600', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 'ti': '0.05', 'lp': '302.25', 'pc': '-15.13', 'c': '356.15', 'ft': '1701942487', 'o': '316.45', 'h': '335.15', 'l': '251.00', 'ap': '297.12', 'v': '2883550', 'oi': '775700', 'poi': '1036700', 'bp1': '302.25', 'sp1': '302.70', 'bq1': '450', 'sq1': '1600'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tk', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43228', 'ts': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20850', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 'ti': '0.05', 'lp': '52.70', 'pc': '-57.81', 'c': '124.90', 'ft': '1701942487', 'o': '122.35', 'h': '124.10', 'l': '22.25', 'ap': '53.13', 'v': '505757200', 'oi': '10148600', 'poi': '1997350', 'bp1': '52.65', 'sp1': '52.70', 'bq1': '2950', 'sq1': '250'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tk', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43214', 'ts': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20700', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 'ti': '0.05', 'lp': '202.40', 'pc': '-21.76', 'c': '258.70', 'ft': '1701942487', 'o': '226.65', 'h': '236.05', 'l': '151.00', 'ap': '193.76', 'v': '15679350', 'oi': '800600', 'poi': '1048900', 'bp1': '202.40', 'sp1': '202.65', 'bq1': '1550', 'sq1': '400'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tk', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43221', 'ts': 'NIFTY07DEC23P20750', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 'ti': '0.05', 'lp': '0.05', 'pc': '-99.38', 'c': '8.05', 'ft': '1701942487', 'o': '5.00', 'h': '10.75', 'l': '0.05', 'ap': '3.21', 'v': '458640800', 'oi': '8360600', 'poi': '4831550', 'bp1': '0.05', 'sp1': '0.10', 'bq1': '1202700', 'sq1': '1220700'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tk', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43220', 'ts': 'NIFTY07DEC23C20750', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '50', 'ti': '0.05', 'lp': '152.60', 'pc': '-27.76', 'c': '211.25', 'ft': '1701942487', 'o': '165.00', 'h': '186.05', 'l': '103.85', 'ap': '142.92', 'v': '24274500', 'oi': '629050', 'poi': '662650', 'bp1': '152.50', 'sp1': '152.60', 'bq1': '750', 'sq1': '250'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43228', 'lp': '52.55', 'pc': '-57.93', 'ft': '1701942488'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43224', 'lp': '102.60', 'pc': '-38.43', 'ft': '1701942488'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43220', 'lp': '152.40', 'pc': '-27.86', 'ft': '1701942488'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43214', 'lp': '202.50', 'pc': '-21.72', 'ft': '1701942488'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43228', 'lp': '52.50', 'pc': '-57.97', 'ft': '1701942488', 'v': '505792900', 'bp1': '52.50', 'sp1': '52.60', 'bq1': '900', 'sq1': '400'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43224', 'lp': '102.55', 'pc': '-38.46', 'ft': '1701942488', 'v': '173143200', 'bp1': '102.55', 'sp1': '102.60', 'bq1': '2150', 'sq1': '350'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43220', 'ft': '1701942488', 'v': '24276700', 'bp1': '152.35', 'sp1': '152.50', 'bq1': '300', 'sq1': '350'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43214', 'ft': '1701942488', 'v': '15680900', 'bp1': '202.25', 'sp1': '202.55', 'bq1': '50', 'sq1': '350'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43206', 'ft': '1701942488', 'v': '2883800', 'bq1': '200', 'sq1': '1500'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43221', 'ft': '1701942488', 'v': '458643050', 'bq1': '1200450', 'sq1': '1220750'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43207', 'lp': '0.10', 'pc': '-96.88', 'ft': '1701942488', 'v': '206012650', 'bq1': '771300', 'sq1': '851700'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43232', 'ft': '1701942488', 'v': '2626000900', 'bq1': '3777150', 'sq1': '2412850'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43206', 'lp': '302.65', 'pc': '-15.02', 'ft': '1701942488'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43228', 'lp': '52.45', 'pc': '-58.01', 'ft': '1701942489'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43224', 'lp': '102.50', 'pc': '-38.49', 'ft': '1701942489'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43220', 'lp': '152.30', 'pc': '-27.91', 'ft': '1701942489'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43214', 'lp': '202.40', 'pc': '-21.76', 'ft': '1701942489'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43228', 'ft': '1701942489', 'v': '505803900', 'bp1': '52.40', 'sp1': '52.50', 'bq1': '8650', 'sq1': '2200'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43224', 'ft': '1701942489', 'v': '173147850', 'bp1': '102.45', 'sp1': '102.50', 'bq1': '1900', 'sq1': '1100'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43220', 'ft': '1701942489', 'v': '24277500', 'bp1': '152.30', 'sp1': '152.40', 'bq1': '50', 'sq1': '550'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43214', 'ft': '1701942489', 'v': '15681450', 'bp1': '202.40', 'sp1': '202.50', 'bq1': '1350', 'sq1': '800'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43206', 'ft': '1701942489', 'v': '2883850', 'sp1': '302.55', 'sq1': '50'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43221', 'ft': '1701942489', 'v': '458649450', 'bq1': '1192900', 'sq1': '1220600'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43207', 'ft': '1701942489', 'v': '206025150', 'bq1': '759800', 'sq1': '847800'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43232', 'lp': '0.20', 'pc': '-99.43', 'ft': '1701942489'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43232', 'ft': '1701942489', 'v': '2626229800', 'bq1': '3569400', 'sq1': '2453000'}
<class 'dict'>
feed update {'t': 'tf', 'e': 'NFO', 'tk': '43207', 'lp': '0.05', 'pc': '-98.44', 'ft': '1701942489'
```

I want to specifically filter only desired values from these bunch of different dictionaries that I am receiving in real time, I want to assign every 'lp' of corresponding dict to a unique variable which should keep on updating as data arrives and also make an empty dictionary {} like - 'tk':'lp' which should also keeps on updating as data keeps arriving in real time over websocket, how can I achieve that ?

Expected output - final_feed_dict={'43207':'0.05','43232':'0.20','43220':'152.30'....and so on } where '43207' is 'tk' and '0.05' is its respective 'lp' from the same dictionary

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. You talk about "updating" a global variable but you don't explain what that "update" really means. Maybe all you need is to append a list with the "lp" values. Why the *pandas* tag?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it in a simpler language, forget about updating part I have taken care of that in the def event_handler_feed_update function itself, all I want is how to fetch the 'lp' data from each of these respective dicts (based on 'tk' value) and assign it to a separate global variable ? there will be total 8 such global variables each of corresponding 'tk' value of respective dict.

Comment: Use a dictionary where the keys are the "tk" values. But you still haven't explained what you mean by updating

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are not definitive but maybe what you need is this:

```
gData = dict()

def event_handler_feed_update(tick_data):
    if (tk := tick_data.get("tk")) is not None and (lp := tick_data.get("lp")) is not None:
        gData[tk] = lp
```

Comment: Thank you for your input which is giving me output like this {'40811': ['301.00', '301.15', '301.85', '301.75', '301.50']} where '40811' is 'tk' and rest are its corresponding 'lp' values, the actual output is pretty long for 10 values of 'tk' as mentioned in original post. I only want the latest 'lp' value to be assigned to the corresponding 'tk' key instead of capturing all the values from dictionaries that are being dumped into my system in a particular time frame (the above output I received with 2 second time interval - time.sleep(2)), is it possible ?

Comment: @ScalperVegeta Instead of appending to a list just assign the value. See edited answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked as expected. I am a beginner python programmer and started learning to get on to algo trading, I would be glad if you can please refer to me some books/material which covers advanced list/dictionary concepts like the one you applied here in this final answer, I couldn't figure out the way using my basic python skill.

Comment: @ScalperVegeta There are many Python tutorials available at no cost (some better than others). Start here: https://docs.python.org/3.12/

Comment: Thanks a lot once again, have a great day ahead.